# how to change the default maximized window size in windows system?

Tags: windows, registry

In my computer, when an application is maximized, the window is always overlapped with task bar. It is really boring and I do not want to use system hook to overwrite the maximized message. Is there any simple way to change the default maximized size in the system? for example, the registry? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[SystemParametersInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can do it for you. Here's the C++ solution. get some breathing space above the taskbar.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")

using namespace std;
int main(){
RECT rect;
//rleft=r->top=0;
//r->bottom=500;
//r->right=1000;
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETWORKAREA,
         0,
         &rect,
                 SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);

cout<<"Old Positions:";
cout<<rect.left<<","
<<rect.top<<","
<<rect.bottom<<","
<<rect.right;

rect.bottom-=32;
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETWORKAREA,
         0,
         &rect,
                 SPIF_SENDCHANGE);

cout<<"New Positions:";
cout<<rect.left<<","
<<rect.top<<","
<<rect.bottom<<","
<<rect.right;

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try MaxMax (freeware)

Review: www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/maxmax-limits-fullscreen-maximized-window-to-user-defined-area/

Homepage: www.kmtools.win-os.pl/omaxmax.php?lang=ang